# Particle System + Collision

Tags: particles

I am having an object, it has particle system with velocity 0. I have a sphere that acts as the collision to collide with the object & its particle system. The sphere did interact with the object, but it seems like it does not collide with most of the particle (as shown in image below). May i know what could be the problem or setting that need to be adjusted? I will attach the blend file in case someone would like to have a look in it. Thank you so much.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Everything is fine all you have to do is change the end frame to your desired value at the moment you have kept both frame start and end for particle system the same,[image] Change that.

if you want the particles to disappear change life time.

Comment: If you found it useful pls upvote and hit the tick mark as this might help others facing the same problm

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. But that was intended to make the particle system to have the same start and end frame. The expected output is while the sphere almost hits the shard, the particle system acts like the small tiny shards that only appears when the glass breaks. Thank you and hope that make sense.

Comment: @CheXuian do you what particles to disappear as soon as the ball is hit?

Comment: Nope, i need the sphere to collide with the particle, but now the sphere is like not colliding with most of the particle which is so weird.